# Which example of code is considered better (in terms of readability and support) and why?

Tags: refactoring, readability, code-readability

Method to get data uses lazy-load pattern, so it's safe to call it multiple times.

**1st example:**

```
variable = large::method::to::get::data()
// some other code
variable.doStuff()
// some other code
variable.doMoreStuff()
```

**2nd example:**

```
// some other code
large::method::to::get::data().doStuff()
// some other code
large::method::to::get::data().doMoreStuff()
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at first, the first method strikes me as much more readable and easier to maintain than the second one. 
If you have bulky code with such long lines, one will find it more difficult maybe not to understand, but to support it than the clean and straightforward option.